# Unable to render page in hostinger l in codeigniter PHP frameworks working fine in wampserver

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have purchased Domin and hosting from hostinger and I uploaded my website on hostinger index page is working fine but when I render my page like contact page or services page it showing like 404 page not found but I working in wampserver.

Comment: I think it's because your hosting service is using a case sensitive file system while windows is not. All your controller's files MUST begin with a capital letter, and all other letter must not be in capital.

For example, "Home_controller.php" is a valid controller's name while "home_controller.php" or "Home_Controller.php" are not.

Answer (score 0):

Most HostingService Use case sensitive

See Codeigniter [change log](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html)

> Changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be Ucfirst and everything else in lowercase).

So you controllers and files name should be:

- Foo_controller (only F upper case rest lower case)
- Foo_Controller (C uppercase) and file name Foo_controller.php may work but I prefer to keep both name same so controller name should be Foo_controller